# What will fungi do in an aerobic environment?

Tags: compost, mushrooms, back-to-eden

This winter I'm considering adding another foot to my wine cap bed so it has a nice thermal environment all winter. That would make it under 2' (wood chip dimensions of 10'x100'x2') of wood chips/leaves within 6 months Will my wine cap dedicate its runners towards the surface to get to the fresh air while running away from the bacteria trying to eat it, or disperse in all directions like it does on cardboard (star pattern).

As I was smart enough to put some on layers cardboard in an inoculation box I plan to put some only 1' deep but on the other side of the wood chip bed to compare the two methods.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, give it a shot. In my experience fungi are very resourceful once a colony is established it's next to impossible (within reason) to stop it.